# Create java bean after database is ready

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javabeans

I am working on an existing project, I want to initialize my bean from the database SQL, before we use `@Configuration` annotation, but here we cannot access to database (it is not ready yet), I need to get some data from the base to create the bean.

we have something like thise:

```
@Bean(destroyMethod = "destroy")
    public Object myObject() {
       //get data from config file
       ........
    }
```

what i want:

```
@Bean(destroyMethod = "destroy")
    public Object myObject() {
       //get data from my database using myTableSevice
       String access = myTableSevice.getAccess();
    }
```

Any help please?

Comment: What do you mean by database is not ready. Are you using in memory Database?

Comment: @SagarKharab my question is updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need some @Bean which depends on `MyTableService`:

```
@Bean(destroyMethod = "destroy")
public Object myObject(MyTableService myTableSevice) {
   //get data from my database using myTableSevice
   String access = myTableSevice.getAccess();
}
```